# How do you concatenate a string with a variable/pass to link?

Tags: javascript, html, string, concatenation

I'm trying to make a simple page to send IR codes to an app on my phone `(OneRemoteToControlThemAll)`. This is how the dev of the `app` shows to communicate with it via html, which works 100% fine.

`>"Send codes using URI "otrta://code?id=xxx" or "otrta://script?id=xxx" - use it for HTML layouts!"`

```
<button type="button"><a href="otrta://code?id=12372">Left</a></button>
```

But, this only works with a `pre-entered id`. So, I want to have a text box with a button that when the button is clicked it sends the code entered in the box. I've looked around for different methods and tried many, none quite working. Here's my most recent attempt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myfunction()
  {
    var code = "otrta://code?id=" + document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
    return code;
  }
</script>
```

html:

```
<input type="text" name="textbox1" Id="textbox1" style="width: 194px"/>
<button type="button" id="submit"><a href="javascript:myfunction();">Submit</a></button>
```

Right now on chrome on my PC this takes me to a page and outputs `otrta://code?id=1234` or whatever numbers I had entered. On my phone the button does nothing. Any solutions on how to make it act the same as the others and work? It doesn't need to be perfect form, just something that will work, thanks for any help.

Comment: see if this works: `<button type="button" id="submit" onclick="myfunction()">Submit</button>`

Comment: @BabakT Okay just tried it, it still didn't send the code (when the app receives the code it vibrates and the status bar 'blinks' red). That definitely seems like the more efficient way to link it though..

Comment: Calling the function from the onClick event won't do anything. The return value of the function (the code) is discarded. Instead of returning the code you should do `Window.location.href = code;`

Comment: How about this: `<button type="button" id="submit" onclick="window.location.href=myfunction()">Submit</button>` ?

Comment: @BabakT great minds think alike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return value is getting discarded. You need to set the `href` property of `window.location`.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function set_href() {
   var code = "otrta://code?id=" + document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
   window.location.href = code;
 }
 </script>
```

--

```
<input type='submit' onclick='set_href()'>
```

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work, nothing happened when the submit button was clicked. Any other ideas or revisions? ...or other ways entirely to go about this?

Comment: @GeneralFuzz - sorry... I meant `window.location.href` but I used a capital W

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the href itself:

```js
function myfunction(link) {
  link.href = "otrta://code?id=" + document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="textbox1" Id="textbox1" style="width: 194px" />
<button type="button" id="submit"><a href="#" onclick='myfunction(this);'>Submit</a>
</button>
```